# Add Library folder to Spotlight privacy folder except Mail/MailData

Tags: macos, mail.app, spotlight, indexing

having some search/index problems with Mail app on old Mac OS.

How can I put ~/Library into spotlight privacy (in order to not index) except ~/Library/Mail

Mac OSX 10.8

at the moment I just explicitly select all folders but Mail under Library into Spotlight privacy part. Not so nice...

Comment: What Mac OS version?  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround..
move Mail folder out of Library and use symbolic link
then I can just add ~/Library into spotlight privacy part

```
$ mv ~/Library/Mail ~/Mail
$ ln -s ~/Mail ~/Library/Mail
```

index/search in Mail app will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
You could just exclude all Library folders except Mail.

Comment: ja, but I have to add new folder in case I install new other applications..